# Remote Deposit a check (By scanning) for non-business users?

Tags: united-states, online-banking

Does anybody have a first hand experience with [scanning a check and posting it](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_deposit) (either by email or a bank web interface) and willing to comment about the experience ?

What Banks in the US support "Remote Deposit" for consumers?

Thanks!

Comment: I was just thinking about this earlier today. Timely question!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remote Deposit usually means a scanner and some software and has a monthly fee associated with it (so it only makes sense for businesses, and even then only some businesses).

Chase and USAA allow you to make deposits via your iPhone which is aimed at consumers and has some deposit limits associated with it (checks have to be less than some $$).

I've used both.  Remote Deposit is super easy, the software usually sucks, but it's too expensive for personal users ($60/month at citibank).  Chase deposits have worked on my iPhone usually after 2 or 3 tries but that did save me from walking to the bank.

Comment: Thanks. What's the cost for an iPhone deposit with chase? I mean do you have to buy the iPhone app? is there a fee per check?

Comment: no fees for chase deposits at all. iphone app is free. deposits are free.

Comment: I've used Chase's app as well. I find it is very picky about the photo of your check; the ads with someoene just holding the check in one hand and snapping it with the other are unrealistic. It works best for me if I have plenty of light, and a contrasting surface to place the check on for the pictures. Make sure you don't get shadows of your hand/phone on the check (light should come from the side).

Answer (score 3):

US Bank just introduced this feature, but they want $.50 per deposit!  No way man.

Schwab has an Android App I have used a dozen times.

1. Sign the check
2. Take a picture of the front and back with the app
3. Wait one day for an email saying I have money
4. Write on the check and file it.

Very easy and pretty consistent.  It worked on folded checks, pictures on a reflective background (kitchen table top), big company issued checks and of course personal checks.

Very positive feeling from this app and the ability to deposit.

Answer (score 1):

Navy Federal Credit Union recently added this feature.  It is free for members  making a deposit to their personal checking account, though you have to be a member for at least 90 days to be eligible.

I have an all-in-one printer with flatbed scanner and availed myself of the service a couple of days ago.  There wasn't any additional software involved as everything was done through the web browser, as shown the [scan deposit demo](https://www.navyfederal.org/products-services/checking-savings/scan_deposit_demo.php).  The only problem I had was figuring out how to align the check for it to be scanned completely (had to place the check in the middle of the scanner, aligned lengthwise; that was more of a hassle to figure out that one would suppose). That was it.  I immediately received an e-mail confirmation that my deposit had been approved and processed.

While [Navy Federal's scan deposit FAQ](https://rnemktg.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/4179) is specific to them, of course, it is pretty comprehensive and gives one an idea of the general restrictions applied to the service.

Answer (score 1):

DCU, Alliant Credit Union has completely scan only options (no need to mail in checks later).

BofA, SchoolsFirstCU allow initial scan, but you need to mail in checks later.

All these are no fee.